# Seq constraint in type definition

Tags: f#, seq

This type definition works:

```
type Model<'t,'u when 't :> seq<'u> >(query: unit -> 't) = class end
```

However, as for me the `'u` is redundant here, but next definition:

```
type Model<'t when 't :> seq<_> >(query: unit -> 't) = class end
```

produces the error:

> Anonymous type variables are not permitted in this declaration - `F# Compiler (715)`

### Compact

The most compact form:

```
type Model<'t>(query:unit -> #seq<'t>) = class end
```

during instance creation:

```
Query.users |> Model
```

produces error:

> Type constraint mismatch. The type `unit -> (string * int) list`
>   is not compatible with type `unit -> 'a`
>   `F# Compiler (193)`

Probably, because of described here [Why are flexible types not allowed in record type definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276568/why-are-flexible-types-not-allowed-in-record-type-definitions). But anyway the error description is unclear for me, what is wrong in substituting `(string * int) list` instead of `'a`?

### Background

The real type `Model` is a wrapper for a database query, it implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and contains `mutable` state of type `Outcome`:

```
type 't Outcome =
    | Empty
    | Loading
    | Success of 't
    | Fault   of string * string
```

The `#seq<'t>` type constraint is needed to detect `Empty` case with `Seq.isEmpty` in generic way due to a query can return `seq` or `list` or `array`

Comment: With regard to the "Type constraint mismatch" error.
My compiler says "warning FS0064: This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by its type annotations. The type variable implied by ... has been constrained to be type 'seq<'t>'.".
It will however accept object creation "new Model<_>(Qu)".

Comment: If Qu in my above example returns a list type then it can help to create the object like this "new Model<_>(Qu >> Seq.ofList)".

Comment: @RobertNielsen: indeed, `Seq.ofList` allows to create the object while the `list` remains exactly `list` not `seq`. However, putting `Seq.ofList` each time is tough, I have created a lot of `Models`. I remember that `#` allowed me in past to pass derived object in a function without a casting. Is this possible to avoid?

Comment: I played around with it, and I see your point, I can't find a way to get rid of the annoying `Seq.ofList` either.

Comment: Thank you anyway. It seems the small helper `let model f = f >> Seq.ofList |> Model
` gets rid of `Seq.ofList`. I will try to use this approach and if it is better (and no other answers) will accept you comment as answer then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the definition

```
type Model<'t>(query:unit -> #seq<'t>) = class end
```

is that the `#` introduces an implicit type parameter, but constructors can't have their own type parameters in addition to the class's.  For instance, you also can't define something like this:

```
type IntConverter(conv:'a -> int) = class end
```

because the constructor can't have its own free type parameter `'a`.

However, the good news is that even if you change your definition to

```
type Model<'t>(query:unit -> seq<'t>) = class end
```

it's easy to accept an input of type `unit -> #seq<'t>`:

```
let model f = Model(fun () -> upcast f())
```

Answer (score 5):

As explained by @kvb, the problem is that you cannot have generic constructors - so you can either introduce a new type parameter to the entire class (as you did in your first example), or the return type of `query` will need to be just `seq<'t>` (as the compiler forces you to do in your other examples).

If you want to keep things encapsulated in a class, one nice trick is to make the constructor private and add a static `Create` method which can have the extra generic parameter that you need:

```
type Model<'t> private(query:unit -> seq<'t>) = 
  static member Create(query:unit -> #seq<'t>) =
    Model(fun () -> query () :> _)
```

Comment: Thanks. 
You answer is good (as always actually) but **kvb's** was slightly earlier, so I think it's fair to accept his one. 
However, your workaround is the most compact among others (`:>_` instead of `upcast`). Love `underscore` operator.

Comment: Yes, @kvb's answer is the best one! I'm really just adding my favorite pattern with static `Create` member.

Answer (score 2):

I guess as long as you are willing to add that helper function you can get somewhat close:

```
  type Model<'t>(query:unit -> seq<'t>) =
    class
      static member Unwrap<'s when 's :> seq<'t>> (cpar: unit -> 's) =
        cpar >> (fun (s: 's) -> (s :> seq<'t>))
      static member New (cpar) =
        new Model<'t>(Model.Unwrap<_> cpar)
    end
```

At least that will allow you to use something like (I think)

```
Query.users |> Model.New
```

As soon as I do something similar with an actual constructor (overload) the compiler says "The type variable `'s` has been constrained to be type '`seq<'t>`'.". So apparently different rules apply to constructors than to static methods (why do I sound surprised).

Comment: Sorry, but the **kvb** answer contains the detailed description of the root cause so accepted it